# How can I put two divs shaped as circles next to each other?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am trying to put two circles next to each other (instead of on top)inside of a container.

However, there's a space between them and I want to get rid of it.  How can I put two (or more) circles together?

https://jsfiddle.net/hLsu9qj0/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    circle 1
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    circle 2
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;

}

.container .circle {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline;
    }
```

**thanks everyone for your help!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you're missing in your CSS is a `float: left` on the `.container .circle {` rule

**UPDATED**

One potential solution to the centering question (from comments) might be to make the `.container` div the size of the circles and center that

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   line-height: 50px;
   width: 100px;
}

.container .circle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}
```

Or, as someone else suggested use `display: inline-block` and then set `text-align: center` on the `.container`

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
}

.container .circle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Just add float left to .container .circle css like .container .circle{float: left} and if you want some space between these divs add margin.

Comment: sorry one more thing.  how can I make it center middle of page

Comment: @user1354934 if you want the circles to be centered middle of the page you have a few options, one of which would be to put the circles in yet another sub-container div and center that within the .container, or, if possible just make the container the size of the two circles and center that (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`. 
And give `margin: 0 5px;` to `.container .circle` to give space between.

You can use `float:left` also.

```
.container .circle {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLsu9qj0/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding float to `.container .circle`

```
float:left
```

check this https://jsfiddle.net/hLsu9qj0/2/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxg0kw9a/)

**OPTIONAL** :
This is for overlapping of two circle.Take a look in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnf3qkat/)
Second Way : [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z7d1r1qg/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle">circle 1</div>
    <div class="circle">circle 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .container {
   position: relative;
   width: 95%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   line-height: 50px;

   }

   .container .circle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left:5px;
    float:left;
   }
```

Comment: thanks this is not what i was going for, but this is good to nkow!

Comment: Oh i see. **Updated** now see this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use float left in circle div

```
.container .circle {float:left;}
```

checkit out this http://jsfiddle.net/hLsu9qj0/9/

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add the float:left; to the circle class. To guarantee also a good alignment, I suggest fixing the width and height of the container and set: height:100% to the circle, check the link:
[//jsfiddle.net/hLsu9qj0/](http:////jsfiddle.net/hLsu9qj0/)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use inside the container 2 div 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
  </div>
</div>

put your code inside the 2 div column it defiantly works bootstrap but you need bootstrap css link inside your .html page
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center them, change width of .container to `.container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 23%;}`